# Are there terms for this class of word pair, or terms for the contrasting members of the pairs?

Tags: terminology

I've been thinking about pairs of contrasting words such as these:

- **go** (to) vs **come** (from)
- **give** (to) vs **receive** (from)
- **lend** (to) vs **borrow** (from)
- **take** (to) vs **bring** (from)

Is there a term in linguistics for such pairs?

Are there terms for the type on the left vs the type on the right of each pair?

Also, I'm not sure if other pairs would fall into the same category or not. Such as:

- **teach** (to) vs **learn** (from)

Comment: I'm struck by the fact that all of these can swap prepositions to move to each other's column.

Comment: The prepositions are just there, in parentheses, to clarify what the words mean even without them for those who don't just see what I'm asking about at first glance. I'm very interested in your analysis of things such as "give from" and "receive to"!

Comment: Can you tell us more example pairs that are or are not members of your set?  _win/lose_?  _buy/sell_?  _heal/injure_?  _learn/unlearn_?  (The latter I assume is not.)

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: None of those would be members of the set. All on the left imply "away from the speaker or some other reference" while all those on the right imply toward the speaker etc.

Comment: What if I say _sell/buy_ (not _buy/sell_)?  It differs from _give/receive_ only by price, and from _lend/borrow_ only by duration.

Comment: Also, _give/take_?  _hire/fire_?  _employ/work for_?  _let/lease_?

Comment: Sell and buy do seem to fit but less clearly so I would only confidently include that pair in the secondary list with teach/learn. I can only go by my native speaker Sprachgefuhl sorry. Though both "receive" and "take" are opposite "give" there is something different that's hard to put my finger on. If there is a word meaning "have taken from me" that might fill the fourth slot in a give/receive/take/X set. Perhaps "relinquish". But seems to make it murkier and thus harder to reason about. Your other examples don't seem to fit at all by my intuitions.

Answer (score 1):

These pairs are **antonyms** that happen to be verbs.

It's difficult to infer too much from 4.5 examples, but they are all possibly **[relational antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Relational_antonyms)** or **[converses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(semantics))**.  (However *go/come* does not necessarily involve an animate relation, but it can.)

(This set happens to include only verbs, and specifically only verbs that can take an indirect object or prepositional object.)

There can be no good label for either column, because it is not necessarily clear which word in an antonym pair is somehow positive or primary.  (For example, why are *give* and *bring* in opposing columns?  Can you define a rule that would work on a larger set or cross-lingual set of relational antonyms?)  So the pairs are orderless.

Comment: "Give" means to transfer possession of something **from** the speaker or other reference point. "Bring" means to carry an object **toward** the speaker or some other reference point. I **give** my money and **receive** my change. **Go** to the post office and **take** this letter with you. **Come** to my house and **bring** some drinks with you. Etc.

Comment: After reading the Wikipedia article they seem to be a subset of **converses**. I only included verbs in my examples because they were the ones that came to mind and seem to be clearest but I wouldn't be surprised if other word types also fit into the paradigm.

Comment: _I gave him the money._ and _I brought him the money_ overlap significantly.  _He received the money._ and _He took the money._ also.  The nuance seems to be that _receive_ is a bit passive, and also _give/take_ and _send/receive_ are not pairs in the set.

Comment: I think _bring_ is neutral on direction.  (You can *bring* it there, or here.)  Not so with _go_.

Comment: No. Though speakers of nonstandard English especially Irish English use it that way. At their core "bring" means "bring it here" and "take" means "take it there". Nonstandard speakers also confuse "lend" and "borrow". This question does not concern itself with other senses, nonstandard or other usage, just with the core semantics. Sorry for my inability to make it clear for everybody. You're missing the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: Not for me, @A.M.Bittlingmayer. _Bring_, like _come_ implies "to a place associated with me, the speaker, or (if the actor is a third party) with you, the hearer". It does not need to be where I am now: it might be to where I will be then, or to a place connected with me even if I am not there.